# Custom fieldname for json data to post to a webapi in aspnetcore

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, mailjet

I am trying to send a JSON object to a webapi using aspnetcore. This seems a straightforward task. But, the fieldname of the JSON data includes a dash(-) e.g `{ Mj-TemplateID : 1}`. Since Newtonsoft.Json is not available for .netcore, so I am not able to use `JsonProperty` to change the json fieldname like below.

```
public class SendData {
   [JsonProperty("Mj-TemplateID")]
   public string TemplateId { get; set; }
}
```

How can I specify a different name to be used while sending json data?

I have to send something like this

```
curl -s \
-X POST \
--user "$MJ_APIKEY_PUBLIC:$MJ_APIKEY_PRIVATE" \
https://api.mailjet.com/v3/send \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{
    "FromEmail":"pilot@mailjet.com",
    "FromName":"Mailjet Pilot",
    "Subject":"Your email flight plan!",
    "MJ-TemplateID":"1",
    "MJ-TemplateLanguage":true,
    "Recipients":[
            {
                    "Email": "passenger@mailjet.com"
            }
    ]
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Newtonsoft.json is compatible with asp.net core, please read: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/977

If you follow that ticket and the following one you can see the progress of it.
A plausible fix is checking the "pre-release"  button in nuget.

Answer (score 1):

You already have dependency on `Newtonsoft.json` nuget in your project.
Just try to add

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

and `JsonProperty` attribute will be available for you.

Why you already have it? Your project has included reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore` [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore/), that has `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/) as the dependency, which, in its turn, uses the `Newtonsoft.json`. So after package restoring, all those packages are available for you.

Comment: sorry, my bad. yes, it works. Visual Studio was not offering me ( as suggestion to fix error) to add "using" on compile error, then I checked the supported frameworks of Newtonsoft.Json and I did not found .netcore. So, I assumed that it does not work.